# cross client (iOS,web,android) + app server + resource (Gmail) - oAuth2, how to authenticate clients

Tags: oauth

I am building a Gmail augmentation that works as a browser plugin and it will also have dedicated iOS and android clients. There is an app server that will keep track of users emails and create augmentation based on certain criteria. Just like Boomerang, or Streak.

I am a bit puzzled on how to implement authentication/authorization, especially when it comes to client - server communication. I don't plan to have a dedicated login process to the app but rather use (or lets say piggyback) on oAuth2/Google. I know I have to keep a token and a refresh token at the server. But how should I handle, for example the iOS client? Should I give it a refresh token or rather just a regular token and have it call the server if the token is expired?

**What is the best practice for implementing client-server communication? Does it make sense to use the same tokens that are used to authenticate to Google servers?**